# vagrant and virtual box errors

Tags: vagrant, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I haven't made any changes to my config... I tried to load it up right now and it's not loading. I was able to load it yesterday.

```
 admins-MacBook-Pro:www admin$ vagrant reload
    ==> default: Discarding saved state of VM...
    ==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
    ==> default: Fixed port collision for 22 => 2222. Now on port 2200.
    ==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
    ==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
        default: Adapter 1: nat
        default: Adapter 2: hostonly
    ==> default: Forwarding ports...
        default: 80 (guest) => 8082 (host) (adapter 1)
        default: 22 (guest) => 2200 (host) (adapter 1)
    ==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
    ==> default: Booting VM...
    ==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
        default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2200
        default: SSH username: vagrant
        default: SSH auth method: private key
```

Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot. This means that
Vagrant was unable to communicate with the guest machine within
the configured ("config.vm.boot_timeout" value) time period.

If you look above, you should be able to see the error(s) that
Vagrant had when attempting to connect to the machine. These errors
are usually good hints as to what may be wrong.

If you're using a custom box, make sure that networking is properly
working and you're able to connect to the machine. It is a common
problem that networking isn't setup properly in these boxes.
Verify that authentication configurations are also setup properly,
as well.

If the box appears to be booting properly, you may want to increase
the timeout ("config.vm.boot_timeout") value.

---

Not sure where to find this file to edit like they state above.

```
config.vm.boot_timeout
```

Comment: can you create a new VM from this same box ?

Comment: @FrédéricHenri Not sure, how do you do that? Will i lose any files or data?

Comment: Just create a brand new Vagrantfîle using the same box in a brand new directory so you do not loose anything

Comment: is there an easy cmd in terminal to do this?

Comment: I think you should try to start the VM directly from VirtualBox and see whats wrong there.